# Disable TeXstudio auto completion of square brackets?

Tags: brackets, texstudio, auto-completion

I've disabled auto completion of `{}` from the advanced settings menu, but the program still automatically adds a `]` when I type `[` in examples like:

```
\item[--]
```

Is this a bug or can I disable it some other way?

Answer (score 2):

For the case you've given `]` is inserted, because `\item[text]` is in the completer. Once you've typed `\item[` this is the only possible choice in the completer. You may disable this by unchecking `Configure -> Completion -> Autocomplete Common Prefix`.

Comment: I've tried that and it still completes \item[